# Does LazyHStack (SwiftUI) release memory for views out of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a simple horizontal list of images. The images are loaded asynchronously, nothing fancy so far.

The main issue is that when scrolling and loading new images, the memory increases and never gets released. In case the images are really big, or the list of items very long, the app can crash while scrolling.
Shouldn't the LazyHStack do some memory management of views? I can not imagine this is not resolved so far, since it seems to me a very basic "feature".

The code (nothing special):

```
struct ThumbnailsCollectionView: View {
    var imageService = ImageService.shared

    @Binding var selectedIndex: Int
    @State var image: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal]){
            ScrollViewReader { reader in
                LazyHStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 5){
                    ForEach((0...imageService.imageCount()-1), id: \.self) { index in
                        ThumbnailImageView(index: index)
                    }
                    
                }
            }.padding(.vertical, 10)
        }
    }
}

struct ThumbnailImageView: View {
    var imageService = ImageService.shared

    var index: Int
    @State var image: UIImage? = nil

    var body: some View {
        return Button(action: {
        }) {
            if let uiImage = image {
                    Image(uiImage: uiImage).resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .zIndex(5)
            }
            else {
                Rectangle().frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            imageService.thumbnail(at: index) { (image) in
                self.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ImageServiceCache

```
    class ImageService {
        
        static let shared = ImageService()
        
        var thumbnailCache: NSCache<NSNumber, UIImage> = {
            let cache = NSCache<NSNumber,UIImage>()
            cache.countLimit = 10
            return cache
        }()
    
        var urls:[URL] = {
            var urls = [URL]()
            for i in 0...100 {
                let index = i % 4
                urls.append(Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(index)", withExtension: "jpg")!)
            }
            return urls
        }()
        
        func imageCount() -> Int {
            return urls.count
        }
    
    
        func thumbnail(at index: Int, completion:@escaping (UIImage)->())  {
                if let imageFromCache = thumbnailCache.object(forKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: index)) {
                    return completion(imageFromCache)
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.urls[index].path)!
                    self.thumbnailCache.setObject(image, forKey: NSNumber(integerLiteral: index))
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(image)
                    }
                }
           }

}
```

Comment: What about `ImageService` code?

Comment: @Asperi I have added the code, it just uses a simple NSCache. Thanks for looking!

Comment: There is nothing about SwiftUI here - you accumulate images in cache which, read documentation carefully, has no strict limit - **This is not a strict limit—if the cache goes over the limit, an object in the cache could be evicted instantly, later, or possibly never, depending on the implementation details of the cache.**

Comment: Not using the cache at all (commenting the call to self.thumbnailCache.setObject) gives the same result, thus it is swiftui keeping a reference to the UIImage as well. I will try to keep a weak reference in the View, and fix the cache. If the limit of 10 is not a strict one, then NSCache does not make my life easier at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try set `null` image when `ThumbnailImageView` outside viewScreen

```swift
ThumbnailImageView ...

.onDisappear {
    self.image = nil
}
```